# How do I constrain movement for lists of Locators using 2nd argument of Dynamic?

Tags: dynamic, locator, downvalues

I need to display edge labels of a graph in a way that allows the edge labels to be moved.  `Locator` seems the simplest and most obvious function to use. My application requires an interface that generates new graphs with different numbers of vertices and edges, so I can't treat the locators individually.

```
With[
 {coords = {{1.08, 0.94}, {1.08, 0.036}, {0., 0.97}, {0., 0.}, {1.94, 0.49}},
  edges = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}}},
 DynamicModule[
  {edgePosns = Table[0.5, {Length@edges}]},
  (betweenPnt[a_, b_, l_] := (1 - l) a + l b;
   DynamicModule[
    {edgeCentres =
      MapThread[
       With[{av = coords[[#1[[1]]]], bv = coords[[#1[[2]]]]},
         Dynamic[betweenPnt[av, bv, #2]]] &,
       {edges, edgePosns}]},
      Graphics[
       GraphicsComplex[
        coords,
        {{Line[edges]}, {Darker@Red, PointSize[0.02], 
          Map[Point, Range[5]]},
         Map[Locator, edgeCentres]}], ImageSize -> 400]])]]
```

[image: picture of output of above]

The locators can be moved, as expected.  What I did *not* expect was that, (even) if the output is deleted and the cell is re-evaluated, the locators retain their new positions. However, I've now learned that this is standard behaviour (see [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg)'s comment below), which can be fixed by `Initialization` (see [Kuba's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46172/4811)).

Also, I would like to constrain the movement of locators to lie on the edges, for which I hope to use the 2nd argument of `Dynamic`.  Can I do it with this (admittedly flawed) design?  My attempts so far have resulted in unresponsive locators.  I think I need to update `edgeCentres` using the callback of the 2nd argument, but whether it is because it is a list, or for some other reason, this is ineffective. I do not know how (or if) I can implement this constraint by adding a second argument to `Dynamic` in the code above.

In fact, I prefer to update `edgePosns`, which is list of the proportions of respective edges that the locators mark, but I need to be able to walk first.

[Related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46185/4811) now split from original question following Kuba's suggestion.

Comment: @Kuba, I don't need to move the edges, I need to move the edge _labels_ (currently shown as default `Locator` symbols).  I prefer to keep the labels on their own edges; the current code allows them to be moved anywhere at all.

Comment: @Kuba, yes, thanks, good example: but in fact I had no problem constraining a single locator to its edge, it is when I have a list of locators (on a set of edges of variable size) that I run into trouble.  I'll edit my question to make that point clearer.

Comment: The behavior you describe is general to expressions displayed dynamically. For example, if you create a 3D graphics object, evaluate it, rotate the object in the output image with the mouse, and delete the output, when you re-evaluate the 3D graphic, the new output image appears in the rotated position of the deleted image.

Comment: To clarify the point of my previous comment, the reported behavior is not a property peculiar to locators, but applies to any dynamic graphic.

Comment: Is this better @Kuba?  I'm making a separate question about the cacheing and possibly another about why my approach failed.

Comment: I used `MapThread` instead of `MapIndexed` because I later want to thread in extra lists of arguments and as far as I know there is no `MapThreadIndexed`.

Comment: @fairflow There is no `MapThreadIndexed` but you can `Transpose` lists that you want to thread so `MapIndexed` will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do that:

```
DynamicModule[{coords, edges, lines, centers, locators},

  coords = {{1.08, 0.94}, {1.08, 0.036}, {0., 0.97}, {0., 0.}, {1.94, 0.49}};
  edges = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}};
  lines = (coords[[#]] & /@ edges);
  centers = .5 (# + #2) & @@@ lines;
  locators =   With[{i = #2[[1]], p1 = #[[1]], p2 = #[[2]]}
    , 
    With[{norm = Norm@N@(p2 - p1)}
      , 
      Locator[Dynamic[ centers[[i]], 
        (centers[[i]] = p1 + Normalize[(p2 - p1)] Clip[(p2 - p1).(# - p1), {0, 
          norm}]) &]]]] &;

 Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[
    coords, {{Line[edges]}, {Darker@Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Map[Point, Range[5]]}}], MapIndexed[locators, lines]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2]
]
```

[image]

Comment: That solves 2 of my problems at one go: the `Initialization` part ensures the state is suitably refreshed and the `locators` code does what I wanted (with the added bonus of `Clip` which is also what I needed, as you thought).

Comment: @fairflow I'm glad it does :) good luck with your project :)

Comment: Cheers: no other solutions yet & yours is perfect for me so accepted.

Comment: The latest edit clarifies the code @Kuba but it does mean my response no longer makes any sense as the Initialization part has gone now.