# Can I improve this sloppy code used with Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting, output, constraint

I'm not an advanced user of Mathematica, and yet I managed to get the `Manipulate` command work to do something interesting. The problem I have is that I have the feeling that the code I wrote is really sloppy and can be improved/simplified greatly (specially the output could be made much better). Say you have a triangle defined by points `p1,p2,p3`, and there is a line that's defined by points `l1,l2`. Given the locations of all this points, the line is used to find intersection points with the edges of the triangle and these new points are used to subdivide the original triangle in sub-triangles and I use area coordinates to do some computation. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
At[X_] := 1/2 Det[( {
     {1, X[[1, 1]], X[[1, 2]]},
     {1, X[[2, 1]], X[[2, 2]]},
     {1, X[[3, 1]], X[[3, 2]]}
    } )]
N1t[x_, y_, X_] := (1/(
 2 At[X]))(X[[2, 1]] X[[3, 2]] - 
   X[[3, 1]] X[[2, 
     2]] + (X[[2, 2]] - X[[3, 2]]) x + (X[[3, 1]] - X[[2, 1]]) y)
N2t[x_, y_, X_] := (1/(
 2 At[X]))(X[[3, 1]] X[[1, 2]] - 
   X[[1, 1]] X[[3, 
     2]]  + (X[[3, 2]] - X[[1, 2]]) x + (X[[1, 1]] - X[[3, 1]]) y)
N3t[x_, y_, X_] := (1/(
 2 At[X]))(X[[1, 1]] X[[2, 2]] - 
   X[[2, 1]] X[[1, 
     2]] + (X[[1, 2]] - X[[2, 2]]) x + (X[[2, 1]] - X[[1, 1]]) y)
Manipulate[
 {P1, P2, P3, L1, L2} = {p1, p2, p3, l1, l2};
 Module[{m = (l2[[2]] - l1[[2]])/(l2[[1]] - l1[[1]]), 
   mi = (p3[[2]] - p1[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p1[[1]]), 
   mj = (p3[[2]] - p2[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p2[[1]]), a, b = -1, c, ci, cj,
    xi, yi, xj, yj, pi, pj},
  a = m;
  c = l1[[2]] - m l1[[1]];
  ci = -mi p1[[1]];
  cj = -mj p2[[1]];
  xi = xi /. Solve[m xi + c == mi xi + ci, xi][[1]];
  yi = m xi + c;
  pi = {xi, yi};
  xj = xj /. Solve[m xj + c == mj xj + cj, xj][[1]];
  yj = m xj + c;
  pj = {xj, yj};
  eq1 = FullSimplify[
    wi1 N2t[x, y, {p3, pi, pj}] == -N3t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  eq2 = FullSimplify[
    wi2 N3t[x, y, {p1, pj, pi}] ==  N1t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  wi = FullSimplify[Solve[eq1 && eq2, {wi1, wi2}]] /. {x -> pi[[1]], 
     y -> pi[[2]]};
  eq3 = FullSimplify[
    wj1 N3t[x, y, {p3, pi, pj}] == -N3t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  eq4 = FullSimplify[
    wj2 N3t[x, y, {p1, p2, pj}] ==  N2t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  wj = FullSimplify[Solve[eq3 && eq4, {wj1, wj2}]] /. {x -> pj[[1]], 
     y -> pj[[2]]};
  {Plot[m (x - l1[[1]]) + l1[[2]], {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> None,
    Epilog -> {
      Thick, {Line[{p1, p2, p3, p1}], Line[{p1, p2, pj, p1}], 
       Line[{p3, pi, pj, p3}]}
      },
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {0, 1}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic], Style["pi", Bold], pi, 
   Style["pj", Bold], pj, Style["wi (both)", Bold], wi, 
   Style["wi", Bold], -wi1 /. wi[[1, 1]], 
   Style["wj (both)", Bold], wj, 
   Style["wj", Bold], -wj1 /. wj[[1, 1]]}
  ],
 {{p1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {0.5, 1}}, Locator},
 {{l1, {-0.1, 1/2}}, Locator},
 {{l2, {1.1, 1/2}}, Locator}]
```

I don't like the fact that I'm repeating code to compute intersection points between the line and the sides of the triangle. I also don't like the fact that I can move these points even to places where the computation no longer makes any sense (for example, have the two line points not intersect the triangle). How can I improve this script? Is there a way to constraint the location of those points in Manipulate?

**UPDATE**

After suggestions, this is my new version of the code.

```
In[1]:= At[X_] := 1/2 Det[( {
     {1, X[[1, 1]], X[[1, 2]]},
     {1, X[[2, 1]], X[[2, 2]]},
     {1, X[[3, 1]], X[[3, 2]]}
    } )]
N1t[x_, y_, X_] := 
 1/(2 At[X]) (X[[2, 1]] X[[3, 2]] - 
    X[[3, 1]] X[[2, 
      2]] + (X[[2, 2]] - X[[3, 2]]) x + (X[[3, 1]] - X[[2, 1]]) y)
N2t[x_, y_, X_] := 
 1/(2 At[X]) (X[[3, 1]] X[[1, 2]] - 
    X[[1, 1]] X[[3, 
      2]]  + (X[[3, 2]] - X[[1, 2]]) x + (X[[1, 1]] - X[[3, 1]]) y)
N3t[x_, y_, X_] := 
 1/(2 At[X]) (X[[1, 1]] X[[2, 2]] - 
    X[[2, 1]] X[[1, 
      2]] + (X[[1, 2]] - X[[2, 2]]) x + (X[[2, 1]] - X[[1, 1]]) y)

In[5]:= eq1[p1_, p2_, p3_, pi_, pj_] := 
  wi1 N2t[x, y, {p3, pi, pj}] == -N3t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}];
eq2[p1_, p2_, p3_, pi_, pj_] := 
  wi2 N3t[x, y, {p1, pj, pi}] ==  N1t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}];
Weight1[p1_, p2_, p3_, pi_, pj_] := 
  Solve[eq1[p1, p2, p3, pi, pj] && eq2[p1, p2, p3, pi, pj], {wi1, 
    wi2}];

In[8]:= eq3[p1_, p2_, p3_, pi_, pj_] := 
  wj1 N3t[x, y, {p3, pi, pj}] == -N3t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}];
eq4[p1_, p2_, p3_, pi_, pj_] := 
  wj2 N3t[x, y, {p1, p2, pj}] ==  N2t[x, y, {p1, p2, p3}];
Weight2[p1_, p2_, p3_, pi_, pj_] := 
  Solve[eq3[p1, p2, p3, pi, pj] && eq4[p1, p2, p3, pi, pj], {wj1, 
    wj2}];

In[13]:= Manipulate[
 Module[{m = (l2[[2]] - l1[[2]])/(l2[[1]] - l1[[1]]), 
   mi = (p3[[2]] - p1[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p1[[1]]), 
   mj = (p3[[2]] - p2[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p2[[1]]), a, b = -1, c, ci, cj,
    xi, yi, xj, yj, pi, pj},
  a = m;
  c = l1[[2]] - m l1[[1]];
  ci = -mi p1[[1]];
  cj = -mj p2[[1]];
  xi = xi /. Solve[m xi + c == mi xi + ci, xi][[1]];
  yi = m xi + c;
  pi = {xi, yi};
  xj = xj /. Solve[m xj + c == mj xj + cj, xj][[1]];
  yj = m xj + c;
  pj = {xj, yj};
  wi = Weight1[p1, p2, p3, pi, pj] /. {x -> pi[[1]], y -> pi[[2]]};
  wj = Weight2[p1, p2, p3, pi, pj] /. {x -> pj[[1]], y -> pj[[2]]};
  {Plot[m (x - l1[[1]]) + l1[[2]], {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> None,
    Epilog -> {
      Thick, {Line[{p1, p2, p3, p1}], Line[{p1, p2, pj, p1}], 
       Line[{p3, pi, pj, p3}]}
      },
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {0, 1}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic], Style["pi", Bold], pi, 
   Style["pj", Bold], pj, Style["wi (both)", Bold], wi, 
   Style["wi", Bold], -wi1 /. wi[[1, 1]], 
   Style["wi check (1-wi)", Bold], 1 + wi1 /. wi[[1, 1]], 
   Style["wj (both)", Bold], wj, 
   Style["wj", Bold], -wj1 /. wj[[1, 1]], 
   Style["wj check (1-wj)", Bold] , 1 + wj1 /. wj[[1, 1]]}
  ],
 {{p1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {0.5, 1}}, Locator},
 {{l1, {-0.1, 1/2}}, Locator},
 {{l2, {1.1, 1/2}}, Locator}]
```

**UPDATE 2**

After some work, this is my most current version (the code is compact, so it's not optimized for speed)

```
In[1]:= (* Shape functions *)
At[X_] := 1/2 Det[( {
     {1, X[[1, 1]], X[[1, 2]]},
     {1, X[[2, 1]], X[[2, 2]]},
     {1, X[[3, 1]], X[[3, 2]]}
    } )]
N1t[x_, y_, X_] := 
 1/(2 At[X]) (X[[2, 1]] X[[3, 2]] - 
    X[[3, 1]] X[[2, 
      2]] + (X[[2, 2]] - X[[3, 2]]) x + (X[[3, 1]] - X[[2, 1]]) y)
N2t[x_, y_, X_] := 
 1/(2 At[X]) (X[[3, 1]] X[[1, 2]] - 
    X[[1, 1]] X[[3, 
      2]]  + (X[[3, 2]] - X[[1, 2]]) x + (X[[1, 1]] - X[[3, 1]]) y)
N3t[x_, y_, X_] := 
 1/(2 At[X]) (X[[1, 1]] X[[2, 2]] - 
    X[[2, 1]] X[[1, 
      2]] + (X[[1, 2]] - X[[2, 2]]) x + (X[[2, 1]] - X[[1, 1]]) y)

(* Intersection between two lines *)    
intersect[{p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {q1x_, q1y_}, {q2x_, q2y_}] := 
 With[{d1 = Det[( {
       {p1x, p1y},
       {p2x, p2y}
      } )], d2 = Det[( {
       {q1x, q1y},
       {q2x, q2y}
      } )], d3 = Det[( {
       {p1x - p2x, p1y - p2y},
       {q1x - q2x, q1y - q2y}
      } )]}, {Det[( {
      {d1, p1x - p2x},
      {d2, q1x - q2x}
     } )]/d3, Det[( {
      {d1, p1y - p2y},
      {d2, q1y - q2y}
     } )]/d3}]

Interactive environment

In[3]:= Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{m = (l2[[2]] - l1[[2]])/(l2[[1]] - l1[[1]]), pi, pj, wi, wj},

  (* Find intersection points *)
  pi = {pix, piy} = intersect[p1, p3, l1, l2];
  pj = {pjx, pjy} = intersect[p2, p3, l1, l2];

  (* Compute weight equations *)

  Wi1eq = Simplify[
     wi1 N2t[pix, piy, {p3, pi, pj}]] == -Simplify[
      N3t[pix, piy, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  Wi2eq = Simplify[wi2 N3t[pix, piy, {p1, pj, pi}]] == 
    Simplify[N1t[pix, piy, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  Wj1eq = Simplify[
     wj1 N3t[pjx, pjy, {p3, pi, pj}]] == -Simplify[
      N3t[pjx, pjy, {p1, p2, p3}]];
  Wj2eq = Simplify[wj2 N3t[pjx, pjy, {p1, p2, pj}]] == 
    Simplify[N2t[pjx, pjy, {p1, p2, p3}]];

  (* Output *)
  Column[{
    Plot[m (x - l1[[1]]) + l1[[2]], {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> None,
     Epilog -> {Thick, PointSize[0.056],
       {Line[{p1, p2, p3, p1}],
        Line[{p1, p2, pj, p1}],
        Line[{p3, pi, pj, p3}],
        {Red, Point[pi]},
        {Red, Point[pj]},
        }
       },
     PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 3/2}, {-0.1, 1.1}},
     AspectRatio -> Automatic],

    (* Node i *)
    Style["\nNode i", Bold, FontSize -> 14],
    Row[{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(i\)]\) = ", Bold], pi}],
    Row[{Style[
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(i1\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(i2\)]\
\) = ", Bold], {Wi1eq[[2]], Wi2eq[[2]]}}],
    Row[{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(i\)]\) = ", Bold], -Wi1eq[[2]]}],
    Row[{Style[
       "check: 1 - \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(i\)]\) = \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(i2\)]\):", Bold], 1 + Wi1eq[[2]]}],

    (* Node j *)
    Style["\nNode j", Bold, FontSize -> 14],
    Row[{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(j\)]\) = ", Bold], pj}],
    Row[{Style[
       "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j1\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j2\)]\
\) = ", Bold], {Wj1eq[[2]], Wj2eq[[2]]}}],
    Row[{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j\)]\) = ", Bold], -Wj1eq[[2]]}],
    Row[{Style[
       "check: 1 - \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j\)]\) = \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(w\), \(j2\)]\): ", Bold], 1 + Wj1eq[[2]]}]
    }]
  ],
 {{p1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {0.5, 1}}, Locator},
 {{l1, {-0.1, 1/2}}, Locator},
 {{l2, {1.1, 1/2}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: For instance, you could start by removing the `FullSimplify`; they are typically slow, and mostly not necessary if you are going to do further calculations on the results anyway. After that, I'd suggest that you consider solving the involved equations symbolically once and for all, and saving the solutions to variables / functions outside the manipulate, so you avoid recalculation.

Comment: You have an `a`, `b` and uppercase `P1, P2, P3, L1` and `L2` defined that are not present in the code. They can be removed. Take all of the `Solve` code outside of this manipulate and solve them once symbolically for `wi` and `wj` in terms of your points. That will reduce the work inside of the `Manipulate`. Constraining the `Locators` is more work. I think you have to use `Dynamic` and apply the constraint as shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46164/how-do-i-constrain-movement-for-lists-of-locators-using-2nd-argument-of-dynamic)

Comment: Alright I followed what you suggested (except the `Dynamic` part which I think it will be quite tough). Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: You have made some progress, but actually we were talking about getting the full solution for `wi` and `wj` outside of the `Manipulate`. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

### Analysis

Key step is to solve for `wi1`, `wi2`, `wj1` and `wj2` symbolically in terms of the input points `l1`, `l2`, `p1`, `p2` and `p3`.

The symbolic solution will be used in the `Manipulate` which will dramatically speed up the process.

Below is the code, some are a direct copy, others have changes.

```
At[X_] := 1/2 Det[({{1, X[[1, 1]], X[[1, 2]]},
     {1, X[[2, 1]], X[[2, 2]]}, {1, X[[3, 1]], X[[3, 2]]}})]

N1t[x_, y_, X_] := (1/(2 At[X])) (X[[2, 1]] X[[3, 2]] - X[[3, 1]] X[[2, 2]] +
    (X[[2, 2]] - X[[3, 2]]) x + (X[[3, 1]] - X[[2, 1]]) y)

N2t[x_, y_, X_] := (1/(2 At[X])) (X[[3, 1]] X[[1, 2]] - X[[1, 1]] X[[3, 2]] +
    (X[[3, 2]] - X[[1, 2]]) x + (X[[1, 1]] - X[[3, 1]]) y)

N3t[x_, y_, X_] := (1/(2 At[X])) (X[[1, 1]] X[[2, 2]] - X[[2, 1]] X[[1, 2]] +
    (X[[1, 2]] - X[[2, 2]]) x + (X[[2, 1]] - X[[1, 1]]) y)
```

While deriving the solution we will define the points in terms of {x, y} pairs. Later the actual points in the Manipulate will be used.

```
l1 = {l1x, l1y};
l2 = {l2x, l2y};
p1 = {p1x, p1y};
p2 = {p2x, p2y};
p3 = {p3x, p3y};
```

Here are several intermediate results defined in terms of these points.

```
m = (l2[[2]] - l1[[2]])/(l2[[1]] - l1[[1]]);
mi = (p3[[2]] - p1[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p1[[1]]);
mj = (p3[[2]] - p2[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p2[[1]]);

c = l1[[2]] - m l1[[1]];
ci = -mi p1[[1]];
cj = -mj p2[[1]];
```

Some of the intermediate results used `Solve`. Instead it is recommended to directly use the solution.

```
xi = (ci - c)/(m - mi);
yi = m xi + c;
pi = {pix, piy} = {xi, yi};

xj = (cj - c)/(m - mj);
yj = m xj + c;
pj = {pjx, pjy} = {xj, yj};
```

### Solution

Now we will solve the four equations. In the original code replacement is used in `eq1` and `eq2` for `x -> pi[[1]]` and `y -> pi[[1]]`. Here we will do that at the beginning. The net result is that the `eq1` through `eq4` results can be used directly for `wi1` through `wj2`.

```
eq1 = Simplify[wi1 N2t[pix, piy, {p3, pi, pj}]] ==
      - Simplify[N3t[pix, piy, {p1, p2, p3}]]
```

The output is an symbolic result for `wi1`. Next we will define a function for wi1 that uses the symbolic results.

In the `Manipulate` the input arguments will be the points `l1`, `l2`, `p1`, `p2` and `p3`. The arguments in the function definition are defined in terms of `l1x` through `p3y`.

```
wi1Fun[{l1x_, l1y_}, {l2x_, l2y_}, {p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_},
      {p3x_, p3y_}] := -(((l1x - l2x) p1y (p1x - p2x) (p1y - p3y) + 
      l2y (p1y p2x p3x + p1x^2 (p1y + p2y - p3y) + 
         l1x (p1y p2x - p1y p3x + p2y p3x - p2x p3y) + 
         p1x (-2 p1y p2x - l1x p2y - p2y p3x + l1x p3y + p2x p3y)) - 
      l1y (p1y p2x p3x + p1x^2 (p1y + p2y - p3y) + 
         l2x (p1y p2x - p1y p3x + p2y p3x - p2x p3y) + 
         p1x (-2 p1y p2x - l2x p2y - p2y p3x + l2x p3y + 
            p2x p3y)))/((l1y (p1x - p3x) + 
        l2y (-p1x + p3x) - (l1x - l2x) (p1y - p3y)) (p1y (p2x - p3x) +
         p2y p3x - p2x p3y + p1x (-p2y + p3y))))
```

We repeat in a similar fashion for `wi2`, `wj1` and `wj2`.

```
eq2 = Simplify[wi2 N3t[pix, piy, {p1, pj, pi}]] == 
  Simplify[N1t[pix, piy, {p1, p2, p3}]]

wi2Fun[{l1x_, l1y_}, {l2x_, l2y_}, {p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_},
  {p3x_, p3y_}] := (-p2y p3x + ((l1y (l2x - p1x) + l2y (-l1x + p1x))
    (p2x - p3x) (p1y - p3y))/(
    l2y (p1x - p3x) + l1y (-p1x + p3x) + (l1x - l2x) (p1y - p3y)) + 
    p2x p3y + ((p2y - p3y) (l1y l2x (p1x - p3x) + 
         l2x p1x (p1y - p3y) + 
         l1x (-l2y p1x - p1x p1y + l2y p3x + p1x p3y)))/(l1y (p1x - 
          p3x) + l2y (-p1x + p3x) - (l1x - l2x) (p1y - 
          p3y)))/(-p2y p3x + p1y (-p2x + p3x) + p1x (p2y - p3y) + 
    p2x p3y)

eq3 = Simplify[wj1 N3t[pjx, pjy, {p3, pi, pj}]] ==
     -Simplify[N3t[pjx, pjy, {p1, p2, p3}]]

wj1Fun[{l1x_, l1y_}, {l2x_, l2y_}, {p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_},
  {p3x_, p3y_}] := -((-p1y p2x + 
      p1x p2y + ((p1x - p2x) (l1y (l2x - p2x) + 
         l2y (-l1x + p2x)) (p2y - p3y))/(
      l2y (p2x - p3x) + 
       l1y (-p2x + p3x) + (l1x - l2x) (p2y - 
          p3y)) + ((p1y - p2y) (l1y l2x (-p2x + p3x) + 
           l2x p2x (-p2y + p3y) + 
           l1x (l2y p2x + p2x p2y - l2y p3x - p2x p3y)))/(l2y (p2x - 
            p3x) + l1y (-p2x + p3x) + (l1x - l2x) (p2y - 
            p3y)))/(-p2y p3x + p1y (-p2x + p3x) + p1x (p2y - p3y) + 
      p2x p3y))

eq4 = Simplify[wj2 N3t[pjx, pjy, {p1, p2, pj}]] == 
      Simplify[N2t[pjx, pjy, {p1, p2, p3}]]

wj2Fun[{l1x_, l1y_}, {l2x_, l2y_}, {p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_},
   {p3x_, p3y_}] := (p1y p3x - ((l1y (l2x - p2x) + l2y (-l1x + p2x)) (p1x - 
       p3x) (p2y - p3y))/(
    l2y (p2x - p3x) + l1y (-p2x + p3x) + (l1x - l2x) (p2y - p3y)) - 
    p1x p3y + ((p1y - p3y) (l1y l2x (-p2x + p3x) + 
         l2x p2x (-p2y + p3y) + 
         l1x (l2y p2x + p2x p2y - l2y p3x - p2x p3y)))/(l1y (p2x - 
          p3x) + l2y (-p2x + p3x) - (l1x - l2x) (p2y - 
          p3y)))/(-p2y p3x + p1y (-p2x + p3x) + p1x (p2y - p3y) + 
    p2x p3y)
```

### Manipulate

In the `Manipulate` we still have to define several intermediate terms, not because they are required to generate `wi1` through `wj2`, but rather because they are used in the graphics.

It is recommended to use `DynamicModule` rather than `Module` inside of `Manipulate`. I also made a column with rows for the output (completely subjective and optional).

```
Manipulate[

 DynamicModule[
  {
   m = (l2[[2]] - l1[[2]])/(l2[[1]] - l1[[1]]),
   mi = (p3[[2]] - p1[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p1[[1]]), 
   mj = (p3[[2]] - p2[[2]])/(p3[[1]] - p2[[1]]),

   c, ci, cj,
   xi, xj,
   yi, yj,
   pi, pj,

   wi1 = wi1Fun[l1, l2, p1, p2, p3],
   wi2 = wi2Fun[l1, l2, p1, p2, p3],
   wj1 = wj1Fun[l1, l2, p1, p2, p3],
   wj2 = wj2Fun[l1, l2, p1, p2, p3],
   wi,
   wj
   },

  c = l1[[2]] - m l1[[1]];
  ci = -mi p1[[1]];
  cj = -mj p2[[1]];
  xi = (ci - c)/(m - mi);
  yi = m xi + c;
  pi = {xi, yi};
  xj = (cj - c)/(m - mj);
  yj = m xj + c;
  pj = {xj, yj};

  wi = {wi1, wi2};
  wj = {wj1, wj2};

  Column[{
    Plot[m (x - l1[[1]]) + l1[[2]], {x, 0, 1},
     Axes -> None,
     Epilog -> {
       Thick,
       {
        Line[{p1, p2, p3, p1}],
        Line[{p1, p2, pj, p1}],
        Line[{p3, pi, pj, p3}]}
       },
     PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {0, 1}},
     AspectRatio -> Automatic],
    "",
    Row[{Style["  pi = ", Bold], pi}],
    Row[{Style["  pj = ", Bold], pj}],
    Row[{Style["  wi = ", Bold], wi}],
    Row[{Style["  wj = ", Bold], wj}]
    }]
  ],

 {{p1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {0.5, 1}}, Locator},
 {{l1, {-0.1, 1/2}}, Locator},
 {{l2, {1.1, 1/2}}, Locator}
 ]
```

The output from `Manipulate` looks like the figure below before altering any of the locator points.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have a couple of concerns regarding the solution. My main concern is that it seems way too verbose. I understand that solving for the weights outside makes sense to make the dynamic module less heavy, but I'd rather have a shorter code as long as I can visualize the results in real time. Also, I just realized that it doesn't work as expected when I start moving the bottom nodes of the triangle (my version doesn't work either). As long as I move the points that define the line or the upper node it's fine though.

Comment: If you want to shorten it you could use something like `wi1Fun[{l1x_, l1y_}, {l2x_, l2y_}, {p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {p3x_, 
   p3y_}] := eq1[[2]]` rather than the spelled out version. Speed was the original goal. I was unable to move a locator point with your original code. I am able to move a bottom node and an answer is produced. I have no idea if it is **correct**. I only attempted to speed up your code and made no attempt at understanding it.

Comment: I'll try what you suggest. I think the answers are fine, but the drawing is messed up. I'll try to figure out why. By the way, do you have any tips to add a constraint to Locators? I saw the recommended link and it's Chinese to me.

Comment: Jack `wi1Fun[{l1x_, l1y_}, {l2x_, l2y_}, {p1x_, p1y_}, {p2x_, p2y_}, {p3x_, p3y_}] := eq1[[2]]` doesn't work because it still gives me the solution symbolically. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Re-read the first two paragraphs. The goal of the answer was to generate a symbolic solution so `Manipulate` would run smoothly.